# Finding peak in 2D grid with traversal

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, divide-and-conquer, array-algorithms

We have a n-by-n grid such that the lower-left corner has coordinates (0,0) and the upper-right (n,n). The cells in the grid all have distinct values, and our goal is find a local peak, which is defined as a cell that has a value greater than its left, right, above, and below neighbors (i.e. the diagonally adjacent cells don't matter).

The thing is, we can only see the value of a cell by visiting that cell (i.e. we can't check the value of (i,j) without first taking (i+j) steps to get there from (0,0)). How can we find a local peak in O(n) steps?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios By wallking through the grid (each cell), how can the complexity be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

It can be computed in O(nlgn) time using a divide and conquer strategy. This is a slightly better time bound than the brute force algorithm contained in the O(n^2) time complexity class.

I have found this pdf on google. Hope it will help.

[Local maxima using Divide and Conquer](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec02.pdf)